# Ensuring user input is a single integer while using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Desired outcome:

- Accepts user input
- Makes sure user inputs only 1 integer value at a time
- Stores that integer in a variable

I tried to achieve this by doing the following:

- Store user input in variable
- Count number of tokens in variable
- If there's not one token, reject the input
- If the input is not of data type `int`, reject the input

Code:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
    String myString = scan.nextLine();
    int tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString, " ").countTokens();

    while (tokens != 1 && !scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Enter a single integer");
        myString = scanner.nextLine();
        tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString, " ").countTokens();
    }

    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);
```

This code is full of holes. The output is inconsistent and undesired. It typically ends by throwing a `java.util.InputMismatchException` error, indicating the value it's trying to store isn't an `int`. I've experienced this error occur after one loop and after multiple loops, even with the same type and quantity of input (e.g. 2 strings).

Should I keep going with this code, or should I try to approach this problem from a different angle?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out, that was a typo in my post, but not in my code, so that wasn't causing any issues.

Comment: Don't you want an `||` (logical OR) instead of an `&&` (logical AND) in your `while`loop condition?

Comment: "I'm getting a bunch of errors" What are the errors exactly?

Comment: @DavidChoweller My understanding is that the `&&` will cause the code to loop until there is exactly 1 token and it is an integer, then it will continue on to store the integer value in the variable `number`. Unless the input has both one token and is an integer, I want the user to have to give new input.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'll clarify this in my post - the code isn't actually throwing errors other than the `java.util.InputMismatchException` every so often. I'm not seeing any patterns. Sometimes it'll run fine for a few loops, with the same input, sometimes it'll crash on the first loop. I've observed a lot of inconsistencies and errors, I'll try to add some to my OP.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete example which we can compile and run ourselves. Be sure to include a class and method. Also describe the input which causes an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your program a little bit. My approach was to accept a single line of input. If the input contains more than one token, ask the user to re-enter input. If there is only one input, check if the input is an integer, if not, as the user to again provide input.

Seems to work for me:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String myString;
    int tokens;
    int number;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a single integer");
        myString = scanner.nextLine();
        tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString, " ").countTokens();
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(myString);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            tokens = 0;
            number = -1;
        }
    }while (tokens != 1);
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(number);
```

---

> **Update**: Alternate approach without using `StringTokenizer`

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String myString;
    boolean validInput;
    int number;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a single integer");
        myString = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(myString);
            validInput = true;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            validInput = false;
            number = -1;
        }
    }while (validInput == false);
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println(number);
```

---

> **Update 2**: Another approach using regular expressions to validate input before accepting it.

The `Scanner` allows us to use a regular expression to match the input. If the input matches the pattern, you can use it to accept the input. Otherwise, discard it and ask user to provide input again.

Here's the code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a single integer");

    String integerPattern = "[+-]?\\d+$"; // positive or negative and digits only

    while(scanner.hasNext(integerPattern) == false) {
        String x = scanner.nextLine();// capture and discard input.
        System.out.println("Enter a single integer. '" + x + "' is an invalid input.");
    }
    int number = scanner.nextInt(); // capture input only if it matches pattern.
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("number: " + number);
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Th OP doesn't mention that the input should be between 0 and 10. I think he's looking for a single integer as input. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Nah, it looks like I did, but I don't understand the need for a tokenizer,

Comment: This seems to work perfectly so far, thanks a bunch! It also has a lot of new stuff for me; I appreciate the learning opportunity!

Comment: I don't think the tokenizer is needed, because `Integer.parseInt` will return an error if there is anything other than an integer in the input, for example, two integers with whitespace between them.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Good point.. I updated the answer.

Comment: The second version is a lot nicer

Comment: @ScaryWombat and DavidChoweller, Thanks for your inputs. I got biased based on the OP's code. Didn't want to deviate much from his approach and so had retained the Tokenizer. But yes, it wasn't required.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, @anacron, but I'm still really new to Java. What is `"[+-]?\\d+$"`? Rather, what would I want to search to find out more about this? Google ignores most of the special characters, so pasting that into a search didn't seem to turn up any results.

Comment: It's a Regular Expression. It denotes a pattern of strings using various symbols and is a pretty standard approach of validating inputs. It's not limited to Java. Most programming and scripting languages support Regukar Expressions. In my answer, the expression begins with checking either an optional + or - sign followed by one or more digits and cannot contain anything else. If the user inputs any other character in the input, the validation fails and is prompted to re-enter the input. Look up "Regular Expressions" on Google and you'll get plenty of resources to get started. Happy learning!!!

Comment: I exhausted the 600 character-limit for comments in my previous comment!! Yayy!! I ought to get a bronze badge for it :)